# VS code program cant find the data directory

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am new to using vs code. I use Visual studio community befor. When I tried to refer to Data directory in the program.cs to define dbcontext it couldn't find it and show an error. As you can see in the image attached. There is no problem if I tried to  reference the models directory. I tried to recreate the data folder and move it in other places but nothing seem to work.[image]

Comment: Trying to make sense of the screenshot. There is no hard connection between a folder/directory structure and namespaces. Often they match but they don't need to. So are there classes in the Mat.Data namespace? Or are the classes that you presumably stored as files in the folder in a different namespace? Just looking into the files whats mentioned there as namespace. Folder Structure is more or less irrelevant.

Comment: If your `DataContext` class is in a namespace like `Mat.Data`, then you should import `Mat.Data` namespace in `Program.cs`.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. @Amit: I am using https://github.com/dotnet-presentations/aspnetcore-for-beginners/blob/main/Tutorial/1-Create%20a%20Razor%20Page/Create-a-Razorpage.md to make a vs code version of my visual studio community 2022 project. Yes it is Mat.Data namespace. I tried to import the file as you said but failed. Could you help with that too?

Comment: It is solved now. I follow another approach https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e2Ax71aksNI and it works now.